# mars mips finding both the lowest and highest character in a string

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

I have tried to move encryption output to a different temp. register, then I load those bytes into another new temp. register. Reset the address back to 0x10010000,  then have a third temp register start at 'a' then if it doesn't equal that letter and add up the address to see if there is an 'a' in each byte, if not add which will stop at a null or  newline byte and then add up 'a' to 'b' etc. Then I have a fourth temp. register to do the same for 'z' but instead of adding 'z' up I subtract it. I have tried this way but it doesn't seem correct. Here is a sample of what I am doing.

```
 la $t6,str1                     #str1 is the string I just encrypted and now  lb                                 moving it to a new register $t6.

 lb $t2,($t6)                    # I am loading the address bytes to this new temp.                                register $t2

 li $t8, 'a'                     # making $t8 to be 'a'

 i: ble $t6, 0x10010000,i1       #I am resetting the address back to zero

  subi $t6,$t6,1

 j i  


  i1: beq $t8,$t2, kvt          # I am testing to see if $t8 equals $t2

      addi $t6,$t6,1            # if not add the address by 1

      beq $t2,0x00,i2           # which ever one comes first, branch it to i2

      beq $t2,'/n',i2            

i2: addi $t8,$t8,1              # adds up t8

      j i              

kvt: sb $t8,($t6)               #now I am saving the new value of t6

     li $v0,4

    lb $a0,($t8)               #load the byte value of t8, and have it print.
     syscall
```

do I have to load `str1` into another string, something like this? `range: .space 2` , if so how can allocate the characters of `str1` into that range and have it read the values?

Comment: What's the point of the `i` loop? Why not just `li $t6,0x10010000` ? Also, `'/n'` looks weird. Did you mean `'\n'` ?

Comment: Potentially going through the entire string as many times as there are characters in the alphabet seems like a really inefficient way of finding the min/max elements. Just go through the string once and for each character , check if it's less than / greater than the current min / max.

Comment: Michael how would I do that? How can I test it by going the string once and print it out the min and max. This is the only way I could think of search it's min and max and to print it out.

Comment: All this is doing is going into an infinite loop.

Comment: And also, the user has to enter characters a-z, so anything in that range.

Comment: And yes I meant '\n' sorry.

Answer (score 0):

here's an example of an simple loop:

```
.data
array: .word 1,2,3,4
size: .word 16


.text

MAIN:

la $t0 array
li $t1 0


lw $t2 array #max
lw $t3 array #min
lw $t5 size

LOOP:
add $t0 $t0 $t1
lw $t4 ($t0)

bge $t4 $t2 MAX
j MINTEST

Max:
move $t2 $t4

MINTEST:
blt $t4 $t2 MIN

j ENDLOOP

MIN:
move $t3 $t4

ENDLOOP:

addi $t1 $t1 4
beq $t1 $t5 END
j LOOP

END:
```